# How to trigger a transition when a component is reused?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

How to trigger a transition when transitioning between the same component?

(With vue-router 1, there was a `canReuse` hook. It doesn't exist anymore in vue-router 2.)

```js
const Index = {
  template: `<div id="app">
    <router-link :to="{ path: '1' }">page 1</router-link> | 
    <router-link :to="{ path: '2' }">page 2</router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>`
};

const Page = {
  template: `<transition @enter="transitionEnter" @leave="transitionLeave">
    <div>
      <p>page {{ id }}</p>
    </div>
  </transition>`,
  data() {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params.id,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    transitionEnter(el, done) {
      console.log('transitionEnter');
      done();
    },
    transitionLeave(el, done) {
      console.log('transitionLeave');
      done();
    },
    fetchData() {
      this.id = this.$route.params.id;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    '$route': 'fetchData'
  },
};

const App = Vue.extend(Index);

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: '/:id',
    component: Page
  }, {
    path: '*',
    redirect: '/1'
  }]
})

const app = new App({ router }).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `key` parameter on the `router-view`.

```js
const Index = {
  template: `<div id="app">
    <p>app</p>
    <router-link :to="{ path: '1' }">page 1</router-link> | 
    <router-link :to="{ path: '2' }">page 2</router-link>
    <router-view :key="'a' + $route.params.id"></router-view>
  </div>`
};

const Page = {
  template: `<transition @enter="transitionEnter" @leave="transitionLeave">
    <div>
      <p>page {{ id }}</p>
    </div>
  </transition>`,
  data() {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params.id,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    transitionEnter(el, done) {
      console.log('transitionEnter');
      done();
    },
    transitionLeave(el, done) {
      console.log('transitionLeave');
      done();
    },
  },
};

const App = Vue.extend(Index);

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [{
    path: '/:id',
    component: Page
  }, {
    path: '*',
    redirect: '/1'
  }]
})

const app = new App({ router }).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: You should use the key property in the <div> in the template of your component (example: http://jsfiddle.net/Atinux/dv0u80Lc/)

Comment: @Atinux what's the difference / best practice: the key property on the router or on the main div inside the component? (on the component, it doesn't update the component's data)

Comment: You have saved me.